# Error connecting to SF object to get the ForecastingItem object description using beatbox - python

Tags: python, api, ubuntu, salesforce, beatbox

from a ubuntu machine I use beatbox python package to connect to SF and get the objects descriptions
but can't manage to get access to the ForecastingItems object. 
I checked my privileges to access the object and I have full access as admin

the script I'm using is bellow, when I changed the object `ForecastingItem` with `Account` it does pull all the object fields.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf8

import beatbox
import pprint
import sys
import os
import datetime

sf_service     = beatbox.PythonClient()
sf_service.login('email@hotmail.com', 'password$numbersletter')

desc_obj       = sf_service.describeSObjects('ForecastingItem')
forcat_item    = desc_obj[0]
forItem_fields = forcat_item.fields

for sf_field_key, sf_field_value in forItem_fields.items():
    print sf_field_key
```

I heard that I should upgrade beatbox to something more than the version `21` to be able to access the ForecastingItem object so I tried `apt-get update upgrade beatbox`, but I still get the error :

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fields_associated_with_an_object.py", line 14, in <module>
    desc_obj   = sf_service.describeSObjects('ForecastingItem')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beatbox-20.0-py2.7.egg/beatbox/python_client.py", line 131, in describeSObjects
    res = BaseClient.describeSObjects(self, sObjectTypes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beatbox-20.0-py2.7.egg/beatbox/_beatbox.py", line 108, in describeSObjects
    return DescribeSObjectsRequest(self.__serverUrl, self.sessionId, sObjectTypes).post(self.__conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beatbox-20.0-py2.7.egg/beatbox/_beatbox.py", line 332, in post
    raise SoapFaultError(faultCode, faultString)
beatbox._beatbox.SoapFaultError: 'INVALID_TYPE' "INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'ForecastingItem' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using an abandoned fork of beatbox, you can get the latest version from https://github.com/superfell/Beatbox

Comment: thank you for getting back to me! any idea how can I use the github repo to install the latest version?

Comment: clone the repo, run setup.py

Comment: I cloned the package to my ubuntu server, when I run python setup.py I got this error : `usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help
error: no commands supplied`
am I missing an argument for the command? Thank you!

Comment: try setup.py install.

Comment: thank you! the update runs successfully, when the update finished, I run the same job and I got the same error, am I missing something that I should configure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67083/discussion-between-mongotop-and-superfell).